Issue with rendering window in SDL2
i am working with a chip8 emulator and I'm trying to implement the display. i got finalized to show a window with white rectangle the issue is when i use the function outside of the while loop the display shows without any error. when i use the function inside the loop i get a transparent window. i used SDL2 and here is the code for the function to render the display.
void test_screen_update(graphic_t *sdl, chip8_t *chip8){

     SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdl->renderer,0 , 0, 0, 255);
     SDL_RenderClear(sdl->renderer);

     SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdl->renderer,255,255,255,255);

     SDL_Rect r = {10,10,10,10};

     SDL_RenderFillRect(sdl->renderer,&r);

     SDL_RenderPresent(sdl->renderer);

     SDL_Delay(400);

}

this is my sdl init fucntion
    void init_sdl(graphic_t *sdl) {
    
      if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not be initalized! SDL_ERROR: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
      } else {
    
        sdl->window = SDL_CreateWindow("CHIP8", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 320, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (sdl->window == NULL) {
          printf("Window could not be created: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    
        } else {
    
          sdl->renderer =
              SDL_CreateRenderer(sdl->window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
          if (!sdl->renderer) {
            printf("Could not create renderer:%s\n", SDL_GetError());
          }
        }
    
         }

}

and this is my struct for the sdl windows
typedef struct{
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
 
}graphic_t;

and this is my main loop
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "chip8.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    chip8_t chip8 = {0};
    chip8.rom = argv[1]; 
    chip8_init(&chip8);
    graphic_t window;
    init_sdl(&window);

    bool running = true;

    SDL_Event chip8_event;

    while(running){
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&chip8_event)){

            if(chip8_event.type == SDL_QUIT){
                running = false;
            }

            emulate_cycle(&window,&chip8); 

            if(chip8.draw == true){

                test_screen_update(&window,&chip8);
                chip8.draw = false;
            }

            delay_timer();
        }

    }



    destroy_sdl(&window);
    return 0;
}

and this is destroy function
int destroy_sdl(graphic_t * window) {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window->window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
  }

and this is delay timer
void delay_timer(){
    static Uint64 last_time = 0;
    Uint64 current_time = SDL_GetTicks();
    Uint64 frame_time = 1000 / 60;

    if(current_time - last_time < frame_time){
        SDL_Delay(frame_time - (current_time - last_time));
    }
    last_time = SDL_GetTicks();

}

